# ctypes, pyrex, swig, or cython for this problem?

Tags: python, swig, ctypes, cython, pyrex

I have about 20 simple C++ classes that represent various probability distributions.  I would like to make these available in Python.  What is the easiest way to do this?  I don't mind having a program automatically generate wrappers, but I don't want to retype the classes.

Also, some of my classes use Boost uBLAS libraries.  Is there a way to automatically pass in numpy arrays from Python?

Comment: How about boost.python?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, none of those.

I use [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) extensively to operate a C++ library from Python.

There are [easy converters](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2006-December/011409.html) for uBlas and NumPy, if you don't mind copying values around. If you do, you can try to get [PyUblas](http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyublas) to work, which enables memory sharing between NumPy and uBlas.